# following ruby.railstutorial.org/ and getting failing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, integration-testing

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3

I am consistently getting failing test errors within this tutorial such as:

```
1) UsersController GET 'show' should show the user's micropost
 Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
 undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
 # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__2659465448390875355_2173812560_4463455946834160058'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

show.html.erb:10 is:

```
<% unless @user.microposts.empty? %>
    <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>   #line 10
    </table>
  <%= will_pagination @microposts %>
<% end %>
```

users_controller_spec.rb:39 is:

```
describe "GET 'show'" do
before(:each) do
@user = Factory(:user)
end
.
.
.
it "should show the user's micropost" do
mp1 = Factory(:micropost, :user => @user, :content => "Foo bar")
mp2 = Factory(:micropost, :user => @user, :content => "Baz quux")
get :show, :id => @user
response.should have_selector("span.content", :content => mp1.cntent)
response.should have_selector("span.content", :content => mp2.content)
end
```

and my app/controllers/users_controller.rb where is defines micropost is:

```
  def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
     @title = @user.name
  end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a total of 14 errors. My other errors are about

```
 Failure/Error: get :edit, :id => @user
 @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

and

```
Failure/Error: test_sign_in(wrong_user)
 undefined method `sign_in' for nil:NilClass
```

I am also using Factory as a test sign in. Im not sure if this could be a problem. I mention this because some of the errors are:

```
  9) authentication of edit/update pages GET 'index' for signed-in users should have the right title
 Failure/Error: @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
 Validation failed: Email has already been taken
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:222:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If you need to see anymore code please let me know.

If someone could direct me to a place to learn more about debugging, that would be a big help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For error 1 try checking your filenames for spelling and case.
For error 9 try double checking which do..end you paste your code into.
Working code for the tutorial can be found here https://github.com/railstutorial

Comment: +1 @Perry Horwich Thank you for the fast response. That repository is exactly what I was looking for. Turns out that I had 2 functions witht he same name and the one with prominence was the wrong one giving me the errors. Also I had functions in the wrong file. I have a lot of learning left to do in rails......

Comment: np.  I made and recovered from similar mistakes.  I finished CH12 and am now pouring through "The Well Grounded Rubyist."  Seems to be a worthwhile next step for me.  Good luck!